# Package name already exists (g-play)

Tags: android, google-play

When publishing my app on playstore I get the following message:

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.this.package.already.exists" already exists in Google Play.
```

How can I find out which app, **com.this.package.already.exists**, corresponds to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the url to the play store app like so:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.this.package.already.exists`